# "Across the board" from an Economics lecture

Tags: definition

You are listening to an economics lecture.

The lecture is,

> You don' need to be a statistician to realize that economic growth in the past 20 years hasn't lifted everyone's boat equally.  ***The good news is incomes across the board are up.***

Would this idiom? "across the board" fall under the definition by Merriam Unabridged's 13'1?

Thank you in advance.

> 1
>   obsolete :  border, side, edge
>
> 2
>   a :  the side of a ship
>
> b :  the stretch that a ship makes on one tack in beating to windward :  tack 3e
>
> 3
>   a :  a piece of sawed lumber of little thickness but considerable surface area usually being rectangular and of a length greatly exceeding its width, in technical specifications of a thickness not exceeding 21⁄2 inches and a width of from 6 to 12 inches, and designated according to thickness
>   
>   
>   — compare batten — see 4deal, plank
>
> b boards plural (1) :  stage 2b(1)
>
> (2) :  stage 2b(3)
>
> c boards plural, slang :  skis
>
> 4
>   a archaic :  table 3a (1)
>
> b :  a table on which food is customarily served especially when spread with a meal
>
> c :  food in the form of daily meals often provided as payment for services
>
> d :  a table at which a council or the magistrates of a court sit
>
> e :  a number of persons appointed or elected to sit in council for the management or investigation of a public or private business, trust, or other organization or institution
>
> f :  league, association
>
> g :  an examination given by an examining board — often used in plural
>
> h (1) :  the exposed hands of all the players in a stud poker game (2) :  an exposed dummy hand in bridge
>
> 5
>   a :  a flat usually rectangular piece of material (such as wood) often marked off or provided with pegs and used for some special purpose (such as the playing of certain games or the providing of a flat or hard surface on which to cut food or set dishes)
>   
>   
>   — see backboard, sideboard, springboard, warping board
>
> b (1) :  a wall or a specially constructed flat usually rectangular device attached to a wall or free standing used for varied purposes (such as the posting of notices, the listing of stock-market quotations, or the display of theater advertisements especially where they may be seen by groups or by the general public)
>
> (2) :  scoreboard
>   < … their passes would leave more time on the clock for New York to put points on the board. — Lem Banker et al., Sports Betting, 1986>
>
> c :  a panel (as of wood) in which electrical circuit components (such as jacks) may be inserted
>
> d :  pari-mutuel machine
>
> e :  any of various forms used in finishing fabrics and knitted garments (such as hosiery)
>   —see 2board 8
>
> f (1) :  a device that is used in bridge for holding the four hands of a deal in their original form so that they may be played more than once (as in duplicate bridge) and that consists usually of a flat oblong container with four pockets for the hands dealt and is marked on its face to show which player is dealer and who is vulnerable — called also tray (2) :  the particular distribution of cards in duplicate bridge constituting any one deal as contained in such a board :  a deal in duplicate whist or bridge (3) :  the entire process of bidding and playing such a deal (4) :  the score accruing to the winning side when such a deal is played; especially :  one match point (5) :  the greatest number of match points that can be scored on any deal in duplicate bridge
>
> g :  blackboard
>
> 6
>   a :  any of various wood pulps or composition materials formed or pressed into somewhat stiff or rigid flat usually rectangular sheets; specifically :  material of the same general composition as paper but stiffer and usually thicker, being in one classification at least 12⁄1,000 inch thick — compare paper
>
> b :  the stiff foundation piece for the side of a book cover
>
> c :  pressing board
>
> 7
>   chiefly Australia
>
> a :  the part of a woolshed where sheep are sheared
>   b :  the sheep about to be sheared
>   c :  the crew of shearers
>
> 8
>   :  an organized exchange providing facilities for buying and selling securitiesor commodities
>
> 9
>   :  a fixed signal governing the movement of trains
>
> 10
>   a boards plural :  the low wooden wall enclosing a hockey rink
>
> b (1) :  backboard — usually used in plural (2) :  a rebound in basketball
>
> c :  surfboard
>
> d :  skateboard
>   
>   < … Tony Hawk has just legitimized the youthful rebellion they'd abandoned along with their boards. — Sean Pamphilon, ESPN, 23 Aug. 1999>
>
> 11
>   :  a sheet of insulating material carrying circuit elements and terminals so that it can be inserted in an electronic apparatus (such as a computer)
>
> 12
>   :  mixing board
>
> ***13
>   :  bulletin board 2
>   — across the board
>   1
>   :  so as to include or affect all classes or categories***
>   
>   < … TV ratings have been falling across the board with the proliferation of channels and the growing popularity of the Internet. — Phil Taylor, Sports Illustrated, 30 Apr. 2001>
>
> 2
>   :  in all areas or respects
>   
>   — board on board or board and board or board by board
>   archaic, of ships
>   :  side by side :  close beside each other
>   — go by the board
>
> 1
>   :  to go or be carried by force over the side of a ship
>
> 2
>   :  to go or be thrown into discard :  be passed by and beyond recall
>   — on board
>
> 1
>   :  aboard
>
> 2
>   :  in support of a particular objective
>   
>   — board·like also board–like \ˈbȯrd-ˌlīk\  (audio pronunciation) adjective
>   < … a pie with an unsweetened boardlike crust made from soda crackers … — Raymond Sokolov, Why We Eat What We Eat, 1991>

Comment: Are you asking for the origin of the idiom?  Or the meaning of the idiom?  Idioms do not "fall under the definition" of one of the words they contain. They have their own meaning.

Comment: What? I am asking specifically "Would this idiom? "across the board" fall under the definition by Merriam Unabridged's 13'1?".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That Merriam Webster definition pretty much covers it. “Across the board” means “in all areas”.

Think of a stock market, where all the stocks are displayed on a giant board. If something happens and all the stocks start to go down in value, you’d say “they went down across the board”. If most went down, but (say) all the tech or oil stocks went up because it was good news for them, you’d have to say “mostly across the board”.

Where there was no actual board, but people recognised that there were many categories, the same idiom could be used: “Contributions to all the StackExchange forums have increased across the board”.